# Mystery: can't login for long time, then normally working

Tags: ssh, router, putty, tightvncserver

I have 2 computers:

- an Orange Pi Zero running Ubuntu, with tightvncserver
- a Windows 7 PC

When I use putty, or FileZilla, or tightVNCClient from Windows to connect to Opi Ubuntu, it can't. It says "timed out" errors. After some tenths of minutes or several hours, it can, and again all programs work.
I disabled antivirus, router firewall, and others, and that didn't make a change in this behavior.
From all Android devices, they use to connect well to Opi Zero with Ubuntu.

I changed from DSL to optical fiber recently, so my router changed. After that, I have this problem.

What can be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Is it possible that another device on your network has been assigned a duplicate IP address? That might happen for example if the old router and the new router reserve different ranges for DHCP

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if I understand but I use an application to check the ips of my computers and I know their IPs. The orange pi has its own ip. It doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: I have the Orange Pi with Ubuntu on wifi and the PC uses ethernet. If I plug ethernet on the Ubuntu machine, connection to it is very slow. It didn't happen before with DSL. It's very weird.